# Wordpress, Sort Posts by Comment Counts

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have tried the solutions on the following links, however, I can get none of them to display posts!

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/displaying-posts-depending-on-number-of-comments-and-latest-comments
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/sort-by-number-of-comments
```

Here is my default code, my question is, how do I get this code to sort by comment counts?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/
get_header(); global $gp_settings, $user_ID, $user_identity, $user_level; 

$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->  

    <div id="content">


        <!-- BEGIN POST CONTENT --> 

        <?php if($post->post_content) { ?>  

            <div id="post-content">
                <?php the_content(__('Read More &raquo;', 'gp_lang')); ?>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>

        <!-- END POST CONTENT -->           


    </div>

    <!-- END CONTENT -->    


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is an example of code I have tried without success

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/
get_header(); global $gp_settings, $user_ID, $user_identity, $user_level; 

$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

?>
 <?php

 $querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'email' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 ?>
 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
 <?php global $post; ?>
 <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
 <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->  

    <div id="content">


    <!-- BEGIN POST CONTENT --> 

    <?php if($post->post_content) { ?>  

        <div id="post-content">
            <?php the_content(__('Read More &raquo;', 'gp_lang')); ?>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <!-- END POST CONTENT -->           


</div>

<!-- END CONTENT -->    

 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: If you're running an SQL query against the default Wordpress Tables, you're probably doing it wrong.

Assuming the posts that are coming up in your page's original query are correct and you just want to modify their order, you can use the main loop's original arguments to construct a new Query and Loop through that instead:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/
get_header(); global $gp_settings, $user_ID, $user_identity, $user_level; 
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

global $wp_query; //Gets the default query
$default_args = $wp_query->query; //Grabs the original arguments
/*
If you find that the above line returns a string rather than an array,
use this instead:
*/
//parse_str($wp_query->query, $default_args);
$default_args['orderby'] = 'comment_count'; //Set the new order parameter
$q = new WP_Query($default_args); //Generate a new Query

if ($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); //Loop through new Query ?>
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->  
    <div id="content">
        <!-- BEGIN POST CONTENT --> 
        <?php if($post->post_content) { ?>  
            <div id="post-content">
                <?php the_content(__('Read More &raquo;', 'gp_lang')); ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <!-- END POST CONTENT -->           
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
<?php
endwhile; endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Just remember that the 'comment_count' parameter is only available on Wordpress 2.9 or later.

Comment: I am using a buddy press theme named buddy that displays thumbnails of the images attached to posts, your example returns only comments, how would I go about finding what the modified query the buddy theme is using so that I can use that query and add the comment_count as the order by?